# how to get radio button values in c# using request.Form?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, radio-button

Html code:

```
<input type="radio" name="searchOption" value="SearchInPage" required>Search Page</input>
<input type="radio" name="searchOption" value="SearchInSite" checked>Search Site</input>
```

C# code:

```
if(this.Request.Form["searchOption"]!=null)
{   
    string options = Request.Form["searchOption"].ToString();
    if(options.equals('searchInSite'))
    {
        searchInSite();
    }
    else
    {
        searchInPage();
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the value in if condition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value from html radio button - in aspx-c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700148/getting-value-from-html-radio-button-in-aspx-c)

Comment: if(options.equals('searchInSite')) : this is not C#.

Answer (score 0):

use `SearchInSite` instead of `searchInSite`in if condition. Case mismatch occurs here.

```
if(options.equals("SearchInSite"))
```

Comment: if i spell it corectly then same error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal.

Comment: @Muhammad Khaja Habeebuddin: enclose with double quotes instead of single quotes in if condition.

Comment: could you plz help me to resolve this issue.How can i compare radio button values using request.form.

Comment: @Muhammad Khaja Habeebuddin: Have you placed the radio button inside the <form> tag?

Comment: @ Muhammad Khaja Habeebuddin : Remove this keyword in if(this.Request.Form["searchOption"]!=null)

Comment: @Muhammad Khaja Habeebuddin: Have add the runat = "server" attribute to the form tag.

Comment: i have used html not asp:html

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:  
     HTML:
       <input type="radio" name="searchOptionPage" value="SearchInPage" required/>Search Page
       <input type="radio" name="searchOptionSite" value="SearchInSite"checked/>Search Site


  Code Behind(C#)
       if(this.Request.Form["searchOption"]!=null)
       {   
        string options = Request.Form["searchOption"].ToString();
        if(options.equals('SearchInSite'))
        {
            var searchInSite=searchOptionSite.Text;
            searchInSite();
        }
        else
        {
           var searchInPage=searchOptionPage.Text;
            searchInPage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: here what is the use of var searchInSite=searchOptionSite.Text;

Comment: to get the radio button value.It is not important just example.Its used for get the radio button value