# C# save data for each radio button selected data to database

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to save radio button selected value to database; not sure how to do that. I found the C# code shown here on Google, I need to modify it so that if three sets of radio buttons are set, I need to save all radio button selected values to database using `foreach`.

```
<table id='attendence'>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="12KQA60079">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ARUNA S">
  </td>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="present" name="Present1" value="Present">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="absent" name="Present1" value="Absent">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="leave" name="Present1" value="Leave">
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="12KQA60080">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ASHWINI S M">
  </td>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="present" name="Present2" value="Present">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="absent" name="Present2" value="Absent">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="leave" name="Present2" value="Leave">
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="12KQA60220">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Das">
  </td>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="present" name="Present3" value="Present">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="absent" name="Present3" value="Absent">
  </th>
  <th>
    <input type="radio" class="leave" name="Present3" value="Leave">
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

C#

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@attendence, @username)"; 

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{  
    int retvalue;
    con.Open();   

    foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)   
    {      
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = con;      
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;      
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attendence", r["attendence"]);      
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", r["username"]);              
        retvalue = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();   
    }
}
```

Comment: @ParthTrivedi am new to this the similar i have done in PHP wehre i use foreach to get all the radio button value the above there are 3 radio button in a group absent present Leave the same radio button vl be generated dynamically wat i need is i want to save only the selected value of the radio button of each group

Comment: do you use asp.net mvc?

Comment: core aspx page? Then server Grid control is the best way.

Comment: im not sure u understood my question  the radio button group are dynamically generated so how can i use the grid control

Comment: @Shaik Kaddadi no 6o bhai tame

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya sorry i dint get u

Comment: May be this will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13050/RadioButtons-inside-a-GridView-control

Comment: @ParthTrivedi thanks for ur support i have a quick question how can the dynamically incremented radio button selected value can be saved

Comment: @ParthTrivedi last question can you suggest me how to save radio button selected value that are dynamically created

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery this will help you

Comment: Also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700148/getting-value-from-html-radio-button-in-aspx-c?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Give id/name for the  .
you can use that id for getting the username and for getting present/absent.leave status.

```
<input id="username1" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="ARUNA S">
<input id="radio1" type="radio" class="present" name="Present2" value="Present">
<input  id="radio2" type="radio" class="absent" name="Present2" value="Absent">
<input  id="radio3" type="radio" class="leave" name="Present2" value="Leave">
```

get username as

```
 username1.text
```

get status as-

```
if(radio1.checked)
    attendance=radio1.value
else if(radio2.checked)
    attendance=radio2.value
else if(radio3.checked)
    attendance=radio3.value
```

Comment: Dude i have already mentioned that they are dymimically generated