# How to get value of Radio buttons in aspx?

Tags: html, asp.net

Can someone please help me I have this code and its supposed to be voting and I don't know how to get the value of the button and count it.
Thanks to all the helpers:)
so here is my code:

```
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Call Of Duty" />Call Of Duty
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Battlefield" />Battlefield
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Assassin's creed" />Assassin's creed
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Minecraft" />Minecraft
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Fifa" />Fifa<br />
        <br /><input type="submit" value="vote">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value from html radio button - in aspx-c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700148/getting-value-from-html-radio-button-in-aspx-c)

Comment: What did you try so far? share some code instead?

Comment: this is my cose so far. I need now to write code on aspx.cs and I dont know what

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in .Net, I would recommend you to use the asp:RadioButtonList this control will help you to retrieve it's value in the code behind in a much better way. This is an example of this:

On you Default.aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLVote" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Call of duty</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Battlefield</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Assassin's Creed</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Minecraft</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">FIFA</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="LResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnGo" runat="server">Vote!</asp:LinkButton>
</form>
```

On your Default.aspx.vb file (if you need this code on .cs you can use a code converter like [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com) to do the job):

```
Protected Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Try

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue = "1" Then
            LResult.Text = "You voted for Call of duty"
        End If

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue = "2" Then
            LResult.Text = "You voted for Battlefield"
        End If

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue = "3" Then
            LResult.Text = "You voted for Assassin's Creed"
        End If

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue = "4" Then
            LResult.Text = "You voted for Minecraft"
        End If

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue = "5" Then
            LResult.Text = "You voted for FIFA"
        End If

        If RBLVote.SelectedValue.Length = "0" Then
            LResult.Text = "You must select an option!"
        End If
        'You can place here other actions, like the code to save to your database.

    Catch ex As Exception
        LResult.Text = "There was a problem processing your vote, please trt again later.<br/><br/>" & ex.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: thank you bro but I need something like that: if (Request.Form["group1"].ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('you didnt press on any choise');</script>");



        }